# PreparedStatement not returning a result

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to use PreparedStatements for the first time, but for some reason I just cant get this to work. The same request made not using a PreparedStaement works fine.

The simple working version:

```
        String artNum = "'" + artikelNummer.toLowerCase() + "'";
        String query =
                "SELECT a.artnr, a.bezeichnung, "
                + "(SELECT verfuegbar_bestand "
                + "FROM getbestand(a.uid)) AS bestand_verfuegbar "
                + "FROM article AS a "
                + "WHERE lower(a.artnr) = " + artNum;
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

The PreparedStatement version:

```
        String artNum = "'" + artikelNummer.toLowerCase() + "'";
        String query = 
                "SELECT a.artnr, a.bezeichnung, "
                + "(SELECT verfuegbar_bestand "
                + "FROM getbestand(a.uid)) AS bestand_verfuegbar "
                + "FROM article AS a "
                + "WHERE lower(a.artnr) = ? ";
        prepStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
        prepStatement.setString(1, artNum);
        ResultSet results = prepStatement.executeQuery();
```

Any help/ideas would be very greatfully received.

Ps Yes artNum is a String not an int eg A1110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PreparedStatements, you don't need to enclose the string in quotes like this:

```
String artNum = "'" + artikelNummer.toLowerCase() + "'"
```

This needs to be :

```
String artNum = artikelNummer.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're still quoting the article number - you don't need to do that any more, because you're passing the value directly using parameters. Just use:

```
String query = 
        "SELECT a.artnr, a.bezeichnung, "
        + "(SELECT verfuegbar_bestand FROM getbestand(a.uid))"
        + " AS bestand_verfuegbar "
        + "FROM article AS a "
        + "WHERE lower(a.artnr) = ?";
prepStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
prepStatement.setString(1, artikelNummer.toLowerCase());
ResultSet results = prepStatement.executeQuery();
```

(Lower-casing two strings to perform a case-insensitive query generally isn't a good idea, but that's a separate issue.)